# How does one express ∀X ∃Y r(X, Y), ∃X ∀Y r(X, Y)?

Tags: prolog, quantifiers

I'd like to know how one express the formulas

- ∀X ∃Y r(X, Y); and
- ∃X ∀Y r(X, Y)

in Prolog.  (My understanding is that Prolog should be able to express these formulas, I can't find anything like them in my Prolog textbook.)

---

**UPDATE**

I gather from j4n bur53's informative answer that, in Prolog, the answer to my question depends somewhat on the nature of `r`, or more specifically, on the nature of the sets that `r`'s arguments belong to.

Therefore, for concreteness, below I describe two cases I'm interested in at the moment (and are fairly canonical).  (As it happens, for both cases ∀X ∃Y r(X, Y) is true, and ∃X ∀Y r(X, Y) is false.)

**Case 1**  Let `r` be given explicitly by the following two facts (and nothing more):

```
r(1, 2).
r(2, 1).
```

**Case 2**  Let `r` be ≤ for the (positive) natural numbers ***N*** = {1, 2, 3, ...}.  Hence `r(1, Y)` is true for all permissible instantiations of `Y`, but there's no instantiation of `X` such that `r(X, Y)` is true for all instantiations of `Y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is to use domain related quantifiers, lets assume X and Y are from domains a(.) and b(.). You would then express it as follows:

```
 ∀X (a(X) -> ∃Y (b(Y) & r(X, Y)))         (1) 
 ∃X (a(X) & ∀Y (b(Y) -> r(X, Y)))         (2)
```

Now the conjunction (&)/2 is directly Prologs conjunction (,)/2. And for the implication (->)/2 observe the following logical equivalence A -> B == ~(A & ~B).

So if we allow us negation as failure (+)/1 for negation (~)/1 we can define a meta-predicate, which is predefined in many Prolog systems (e.g. [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=forall/2)), as follows:

```
forall(F, G) :- \+ (F, \+ G).
```

So that, if we accept all the transformations here, then in the end the two queries would amount the the following Prolog queries.

```
?- forall(a(X), (b(Y),r(X,Y))).
?- a(X), forall(b(Y), r(X,Y)).
```

The approach usually works for Datalog, but doesn't in these circumstances:

- If a(.) or b(.) are infinite.
- If r(.,.) has further parameters, i.e. negation of failure discards bindings.
- If classical reasoning is need, i.e. negation of failure is too weak here
- If constraints are involved, we might desire foreach/2 instead forall/2.
- What else?